# Termux: Different scrolling behaviour after "screen"-command

Tags: ssh, scroll, openssh, termux

I'm using Termux to work with the shell on my Android smartphone. I installed openssh in termux, so I can log into my raspberry from there. Whether I work locally or remotely, termux reacts to any swipe-up or swipe-down gesture by scrolling through the screen-content as expected.

However, when I use the "screen" command for a session, scrolling is impossible. The same touch-gestures that did the scrolling before, now produce cursor up and cursor down events which results in going up and down the command history of the shell.

How can I change that behaviour to scrolling the screen content within my "screen" session?

I read a lot of screen man-pages and other docs and got the impression that I might have to deal with TERMCAP and/or TERMINFO but did not really understand what I was reading.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my guesses were not too bad.

There was a line contained in /etc/screenrc (commented out there).

`#termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@`

So I created this ~/.screenrc
which did it:

`termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@`